# KL divergence and Wasserstein distance

Tags: kullback-leibler, divergence

While reading the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.11780.pdf, I have some confusion parts as below:

> The KL divergence is not only problematic for representation learning
> due to the statistical limitations described in Theorem 1, but also
> due to its property of being completely agnostic to the metric of the
> underlying data distribution, and invariant to any invertible
> transformation. KL divergence is sensitive to small differences in the
> data samples. When used for representation learning, the encoder can
> often only represent small parts of the data samples, since any small
> differences found is sufficient to maximize the KL divergence.

What I don't understand is the following

1. KL divergence is agonistic to the metric of the underling data distribution
2. KL divergence is invariant to invertible transformation
3. KL divergence is sensitive to small differences in the data samples
4. any small differences found is sufficient to maximize the KL divergence

I want to know the underlying meaning of the above sentences.
Would you elaborate them?

Comment: Why does the question have *Wasserstein distance* in its title?

Comment: Because the paper referred to the above sentence while comparing with Wasserstein distance

Comment: Is your question itself related to that though?

Comment: I admit that there are some missing points in the questions. The reason I include Wasserstein distance in the title is that the properties of KL divergence is mentioned in comparison with Wasserstein distance in the paper.